# How to create letter sequence?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to create letter sequence in SQL Server ? Like A,B,C....Z,AA,AB... I refer this 
   [Given Letter, Get Next Letter in Alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179007/given-letter-get-next-letter-in-alphabet) link but it will not work after letter Z.How to do this?

Comment: When do you want it to stop?

Comment: Number of elements dynamically changing.

Comment: How do you intend to prevent the spelling of foul language words?

Answer (score 4):

You can just use arithmetic.  This is going to assume that you have numbers in a table (however you want to generate them):

```
select (case when (n / 26) % 27 = 0 then ''
             else char(ascii('A') +  (n / 26) % 27 - 1)
        end) +
       char(ascii('A') + n % 26)
from numbers n;
```

For instance:

```
select (case when (n / 26) % 27 = 0 then ''
             else char(ascii('A') +  (n / 26) % 27 - 1)
        end) +
       char(ascii('A') + n % 26)
from (select top 100 row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as n
      from master..spt_values
     ) n;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/955) is a SQL Fiddle.  Longer sequences can be generated using the same logic.

An alternative method is to put together a sequence of letters and then just `cross join` to put them together:

```
with letters as (
      select top 26
             char(ascii('A') + row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1) as letter
      from master..spt_values
     )
select l1.letter as seq
from letters l1
union all
select l1.letter + l2.letter
from letters l1 cross join letters l2
union all
select l1.letter + l2.letter + l3.letter
from letters l1 cross join letters l2 cross join letters l3
order by len(seq), seq;
```

This is a bit challenging because the sequences have different lengths.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/959) is a SQL Fiddle illustrating this approach.

Comment: This is works for me and i also manage the number of elements that i want. Thank you

Comment: How do you intend to avoid the inevitable generation of foul language words?

Comment: @JeffModen I actually created and checked this sequence up to 500 numbers (500 is more than enough for me)

Comment: @ArunKPushpakaran - 500 numbers won't get you very far.  It'll not be long before you get into "swear word" territory.

Answer (score 0):

> *****here we use generate_series() function to generate a series of number.Specify numbers from where to where you need to generate sequence of numbers. And chr() fucntion returns the ASCII value of those number
> from*****

```
select chr(generate_series(65,90));
```

Comment: Good idea but Generate_Series() is not yet available because SQL Server 2022 has not yet been released for production use by the public.

Comment: you can try it in postgresql it works good in Postgres

Comment: Look at the tags for this post... nothing about Postgres in the tags.